# Cannot generate apk with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation, apk

I'm having an error to generate the apk file in flutter

On debug mode it doens't happend

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

I doesn't know what to to

Someone can help?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

first, if you have not set a `sign key` for release version, you should set a it for your release (see [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)). Otherwise if you have set it, You should check the informations in the `key.properties` file, eg. `keyAlias`, `storeFile`. If this file is not similar to your signature file, you will get this error.